# how to replace half space to space in persian language in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

Please tell me how to replace half space into space in `sql server`
 for exaple: `بی‌ام‌و  to بی ام و`

```
select  *
from    test
where   title   like    N'%بی‏ام‏و%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand what do you mean by half space . But you can use Replace function to replace characters .

Answer (score 0):

It is very important to get unicode of half-space or hidden character or zero-width space,
some times it is "8204" or other times is "8203"
in following example we get unicode number by substring and then replace it, the other thing that is important is collate for me it just works with "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"

```
 DECLARE @UnicodeReplace NVARCHAR(5) = N'ی‌آ'
    -- check that unicode string length is 3,
    -- and prove existence of zero-width space character matching unicode 8204
    SELECT @UnicodeReplace AS String,
       LEN(@UnicodeReplace) AS Length,
           UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@UnicodeReplace, 2, 1)) AS UnicodeValue  -- it gets you 8204

  set @UnicodeReplace = N'ی‌آ' collate  Persian_100_CI_AS --+ NCHAR(8204)
-- replace and prove the unicode string length is reduced to 2
SELECT REPLACE(@UnicodeReplace  collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS , NCHAR(8204), ''),
       LEN(REPLACE(@UnicodeReplace   collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS , NCHAR(8204), '')) AS Length
```